Oh no something has gone wrong
I've been looking at other answers, but haven't gotten anywhere. apt is updated and upgraded. When I use ctrl-alt-f3 to get a shell I see the system is initialized - wifi is connected and all disks are mounted. Hitting "logout" just goes dark for a short time and returns me to "Oh no".
When I hit ctrl-alt-f1 I get the gui login screen, so even the graphics seems to be working. From there I have tried logging in as all the other users on my system and they have the same problem, so it appears not to be a user configuration issue. The end of the journal log is here, if anyone wants to look, I see a bunch of errors but don't know if some are expected. I don't believe I made any major changes before the last time I shut it down normally.
My system is a relatively newly loaded 24.04. I'd like to try reloading the OS on top, but my load image doesn't seem to give me that choice - the options are to use the entire disk (I have a windows partition I don't want to lose) or to "load in a new partition besides windows and ubuntu 24.04". Didn't it used to offer to reload an existing system while trying to preserve the user data? Is there no way to do that anymore?
This question is not uncommon and I've tried a lot of suggestions, but I haven't seen any with quite the same symptoms, where I can get the login gui but all users fail to log in.

The output of journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell -n50 --no-pager could be helpful

Thanks, here it is: https://young-0.com/journalctl-gnome-shell.txt

You don't seem to state exactly what the problem is.

I looked at .bash_history and found I had done apt install ntfs-3g the last time I had logged in. I tried uninstalling it but it made no difference.

@OrganicMarble All users get the "Oh no something has gone wrong" screen on startup

I tried debsums and found it was missing all the icons from yaru-theme-icon and humanity-icon-theme. I reinstalled those packages, and debsums now shows no problems, but when I rebooted it still went to "oh no".
